# Cookies Set but not Sent in Subsequent Requests

Tags: membershipreboot

I'm preparing a demo of MembershipReboot for my local user group. I'm experiencing a strange scenario whereby the 2 cookies:

1. FedAuth; and
2. FedAuth1

are being set in the headers of the Response. However, in subsequent Requests, they are not part of the headers. I confirmed this using Fiddler and it explains why User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false after successful logins.

Is the anything which may be leading to this weird scenario?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a few subtle errors in my Web.config file.

**In the configSections element**

Instead of:

```
<section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

I had:

```
<section name="system.identitymodel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
```

**In the system.webServer > modules element**

Instead of:

```
<add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
```

I had:

```
<add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

**For the system.identityModel.services element**

Instead of:

```
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" persistentSessionLifetime="30:00:00"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

I had:

```
<system.identitymodel.services>
    <federationconfiguration>
      <cookiehandler requiressl="false" persistentSessionLifetime="30:00:00" />
    </federationconfiguration>
</system.identitymodel.services>
```

This was tough to diagnose, so always be careful when configuring your application!

MembershipReboot rocks!!!